# Integrating $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac1{a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)+c}dt$ with $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1<c$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-integration

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=1<c$.

Find $I:=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)+c}dt$.

So, I set $z=e^{it}$ and then $dz=ie^{it}dt$ and so $\frac{dz}{iz}=dt$. Therefore,

$\begin{align*} I & =\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz/z}{a\cdot\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}+b\cdot\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}+c} \newline &=\frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{a\cdot(z^2+1)-ib\cdot(z^2-1)+2cz} \newline &=\frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(a-ib)z^2+2cz+a+ib}\newline &= \frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z-z_+)(z-z_-)}\end{align*}$

Where $z_{\pm}=\frac{-2c\ \pm\ \sqrt{4c^2-4(a+ib)(a-ib)}}{2(a-ib)}=\frac{-c\ \pm\ \sqrt{c^2-(a^2+b^2)}}{(a-ib)}=\frac{-c\ \pm\ \sqrt{c^2-1}}{(a-ib)}$.

Therefore, if we define $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-z_-}$, we get that $f$ is analytic in $\{z:|z|\leq 1\}$ since 
$$|z_-|=\Bigg|\frac{-c-\sqrt{c^2-1}}{a-ib}\Bigg|=\bigg|c+\sqrt{c^2-1}\bigg|>|c|>1$$

Finally from Cauchy's Integral Formula:

$$I=\frac{2}{i}\cdot 2\pi i\cdot f(z_+)=4\pi \frac{1}{z_+-z_-}=\frac{2\pi(a-ib)}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}$$
Which is not always real... So my question is what is the problem.

Moreover, sometimes it is correct, e.g. $a=1,b=0,c=2$ gives the correct answer $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Comment: The step $$\frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(a-ib)z^2+2cz+a+ib}= \frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(z-z_+)(z-z_-)}$$ should read $$\frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(a-ib)z^2+2cz+a+ib}= \frac{2}{i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{(a-ib)(z-z_+)(z-z_-)}$$ since the leading coefficient of the quadratics in the denominator is $a-ib$. Now your final result is much prettier...

Comment: An alternative see that the integral the integral does not depend of $a$ and $b$ is to remark that as $a^2+b^2=1$ there exists $\phi$ such that $a=\cos(\phi), b=\sin(\phi)$ so using a trigonometric formula, a change of variables and periodicity:
$$I=\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\cos(t+\phi)+c}dt=\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{\cos(t)+c}dt$$

Comment: @Did I have one more question. Why is it not problematic (for the use of Cauchy integral formula) that the curve on which we integrate, i.e. $|z|=1$, is not "centered" at $z_+$.

Comment: Because nothing in Cauchy integral formula imposes the curve to be the circle centered at a specific point. 1. What are your sources on basic complex analysis? 2. How come you still have questions about the heart of the problem 8 hours after you accepted an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos(t)+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sin(t) = \cos(t-\delta) 
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\delta=\cos^{-1}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{c+a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)} = \int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{c+\cos(t-\delta)} =\int^{2\pi-\delta}_{-\delta}\frac{dt}{c+\cos(t)}.
\end{align}
However, since $(c+\cos(t))^{-1}$ is $2\pi$ period, then the integral is equivalent to 
\begin{align}
\int^{2\pi}_0 \frac{dt}{c+\cos(t)} =\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}
\end{align}
where the evaluation is done with contour integral.

Comment: Wolfy says that 
$\int \dfrac{dt}{\cos(t) + c} 
= -\dfrac{2 \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{(c - 1) \tan(t/2)}{\sqrt{1 - c^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1 - c^2}}$.